# How do you avoid memory leaks in Spark/Pyspark for multiple dataframe edits and loops?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, memory-management, memory-leaks

There are 2 scenarios that I feel cause memory leaks that I struggle to know how to avoid.

**Scenario 1:**

There is a need to perform multiple edits to a df like below:

```
df = method1()
df = method2(df)
df = method3(df)
```

If I'm not mistaken, this approach is discouraged because each df is lengthening the memory footprint.  How do you get around this?

**Scenario 2:**

There is a need to execute looping in pyspark. For example, Let's say I have 400 files I need to execute a transformation on and I loop through 10 at a time --> read in 10 files, transform data, write back out to file...loop again.  This feels like it is also causing a memory leak.

Should we be persisting data in both scenarios?  How do we prevent memory build up?  Is there a way to refresh/kill the spark context but maintain the looping so force release any memory usage?

Comment: This is not how Spark works. Spark has a lazy execution so whatever transformations in multiple methods they won't be executed instantly, also no need to read the input in chunks, this should be handled by Spark automatically. The question is why do you think there is a memory leak? What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

## Scenario 1

This is NOT discouraged. Since Spark DataFrames are lazily executed, you can make as many modifications as you like to a DataFrame in this manner, and you are simply replacing a DataFrame with a new DataFrame with all the previous instructions plus new instructions from the latest call. No data is rendered until you call an "action" method on a DataFrame such as count, collect, show, or write.

## Scenario 2

If on every loop you are reading from source files and writing to new files, you aren't leaking anything.